# Get "Cannot find git repository in any parent directory" when deploying Spring app to Heroku with GitHub

Tags: git, heroku

I have a repo (https://github.com/hukacode/titama), it's an app (Spring Boot + Angular)

I signup for a Heroku account, create an app, connect to this Repo, then choose "develop" as a branch to deploy.

When I push a new code, I get these logs:

```sh
-----> Gradle app detected
-----> Spring Boot detected
-----> Installing JDK 11... done
-----> Building Gradle app...
-----> executing ./gradlew build -x test
       Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-bin.zip
       .........10%..........20%..........30%..........40%..........50%.........60%..........70%..........80%..........90%..........100%
       To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
       Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing
       
       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
       
       * What went wrong:
       A problem occurred configuring root project 'titama'.
       > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
          > Cannot find git repository in any parent directory
          > Cannot find git repository in any parent directory
       
       * Try:
       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
       
       * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
       
       BUILD FAILED in 26s
 !     ERROR: Failed to run Gradle!
```

I tried to ./gradlew build -x test on local, it worked.

I tried to create a new branch, delete all code, create a simple Spring Boot project, it worked too.

Does anybody get "Cannot find git repository in any parent directory"?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem.
I try to comment out "ratchetFrom" in "spotless" configuration then it works.

```
spotless {
    // ratchetFrom 'origin/main'
    ...
}
```

Update:

This is a workaround from spotless

https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues/752#issuecomment-746978258